Why sheaves of abelian groups form an abelian category
I know it is an elementary result. But some details confuse me.

In Vakil's The Rising Sea (version 2022) Theorem 2.6.2 writes:

Sheaves of abelian groups on a topological space $X$ form an abelian category.

In this section (2.6), he already proved sheaves of abelian groups admit kernel and cokernel.



Here are my questions, in sheaves of abelian groups, how to show:
Every monomorphism is kernel of its cokernel.
And every epimorphism is cokernel of its kernel.



Assume $\mathscr{F}\overset{\phi}{\rightarrowtail}\mathscr{G}\twoheadrightarrow\text{Coker}\phi$.
And $\mathscr{F},\ \mathscr{G},\ \text{Coker}\phi$ are sheaves of abelian group (on a topological space $X$).
Because category of abelian group is abelian, since $\text{Coker}(\phi_p)\cong (\text{Coker}\phi)_p$,
So at the level of stalks, $\mathscr{F}_p\cong\text{Ker}\ \text{Coker}\ \phi_p$.

The problem is that:
Two sheaves with isomorphic stalks may not be isomorphic sheaves.
So I can't conclude that $\mathscr{F}\cong \text{Ker}\ \text{Coker}\ \phi$.

As a hint, can you try to construct a map from $\mathscr{F}$ to $\operatorname{ker} \operatorname{coker} \phi$, or vice versa, perhaps using some universal property; and then try to show that that particular map induces an isomorphism on stalks?


The problem is that: two sheaves with isomorphic stalks may not be isomorphic sheaves.

This is true for sure; however, if we have a morphism of sheaves
$$
\phi: \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{G}
$$
such that $\phi$ induces an isomorphism $\mathcal{F}_x \stackrel{\sim}{\to} \mathcal{G}_x$ for all points $x$, then indeed $\phi$ is an isomorphism. (We can define $\phi^{-1}$ on an open set $U$ as follows: build a little local $\phi^{-1}$ in a neighborhood $U_x$ at each point $x$ in $U$, and argue that these have to agree on the overlaps.)
